# how can I print image from fetch API using window print?

Tags: javascript, html, api, printing, pdf-generation

how can I print image from fetch API using window print?
the image has appeared on the page, but when the popup window appears, the image is gone

```
async function fetchImage() {
      let response = await fetch(base_url_image + nopers + '/noTam/' + notam + '/download');
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
      }
      return await response.blob();
    }
    
    fetchImage().then((blob) => {
        imagePers = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        document.getElementById('fotoPersonel').innerHTML += `<img src="${imagePers}" alt="foto personel">`;
      }).then(() => {
        window.print();
      })
      .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
      window.close();
```